# Crontab can't execute command in script

Tags: bash, sh, cron

I have shell script i've written that deletes the oldest logfile in a directory when the mount point reaches 90% capacity. When I run the script manually it works fine but when I attempt to use crontab to run it cannot seem to execute the actual rm command but it executes everything else in the script. See my crontab and script below.

```
0 * * * *  /acsmgmt/iselogs/iselogcleanup.sh

#!/bin/bash
df -H | grep /acsmgmt | awk '{ print $4 " " $5 }' | while read output;
do
    #!echo $output
    usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1 }' | cut -d '%' -f1)
    #!echo $usep

    if [ $usep -ge 90 ]; then
            echo $(date) "Logs cleaned up" >> /tmp/isecleanup.log
            rm -v `ls /acsmgmt/iselogs -rt | grep "iselog-" | head -1` >> /tmp/isecleanup.log
    else
            echo $(date) "No logs to clean up" >> /tmp/isecleanup.log
    fi
done
```

Comment: Is the script producing any errors when running under cron?  You may want to redirect stdout/stderr for the script to a file using something like `0 * * * *  /acsmgmt/iselogs/iselogcleanup.sh > /tmp/errors 2>&1`, and then look at that file after the script runs.

Comment: Just tried that. No output is showing up in the errors file. Cron can execute everything in the script except this statement rm -v `ls /acsmgmt/iselogs -rt | grep "iselog-" | head -1` >> /tmp/isecleanup.log. All my echos are showing up

Comment: Perhaps try `iselog=$(ls /acsmgmt/iselogs -rt | grep "iselog-" | head -1)` then do `rm -v $iselog >> /tmp/isecleanup.log`

Comment: If have that `ls` pipeline output to the file do you see the correct output in the log?

Comment: Got it working using I'L'I's idea with a few modifications. Cron couldn't find head so I head to use absolute path. Also I had to use append absolute path to the $iselog variable so rm knew were it was.

Comment: Do you really want to call the check 24 times a day? Once an hour? (that's fine, I'm just making sure you know that it will execute every hour)

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer is indeed, as I suspected, to always make sure you specify a correct and complete `PATH` variable in any script called by `cron`.

(I keep making this same mistake myself, even after years of writing cron scripts -- some versions of cron allow you to specify a default PATH (and other environment variables) for all your scripts, and this can help, but it also needs careful maintenance.)